# Postman read from csv data file. Need new url for each iteration

Tags: path, postman

I have read the excellent documentation 'Working with data files"
which handles the case:

```
path, value
post, 1
post, 2
post, 3
post, 4
```

so the path is valid for one iteration, within the iteration many posts can be processed.

My scenario is a little different since the customer numbers I process are passed in the URL:

https://tapy-uat.flyrit.de/clm/unbprocessor/sales/pt/identifiers/no=876498712

so I would have:
https://tapy-uat.flyrit.de/clm/unbprocessor/sales/pt/identifiers/no={{path}}
and the rest of the API call is unchanged, i.e.

```
path, value1
path, value2
path, value3
path, value4
path, value5
```

is there a way to iterate so that each api call is made to a new url?

I envision executing from Collection Runner and looping thru all customer numbers from the csv file passing for each iteration the customer number to the {{path}} variable in the url.

Comment: How you described it is exactly how it works, I'm not sure that I understand what the problem is what problems you're running into

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have solved it. Actually I need only one column for the URL variable:

https://tapy-uat.flyrit.de/clm/unbprocessor/sales/pt/identifiers/no={{path}}

```
path
4567459687
4357349584
2396504398
4572839495
```

and the iteration is done with each Customer Number giving a new URL